# context dependent validation for BeanValidation

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am a big fan of JSR 303 BV but in my current project i am having a lot of "context dependent validation" and i do not find any reasonable approach to implement them with BV.
Basically validation rules can depend on

- logged in user (it is stored in http request)
- a user we act upon - the id of the user is path param of REST URL like /foo/bar/user/1/sth
- both of these

A little example :

```
class Alphabet{
@Valid
private Alpha a;
@Valid
private Beta b;
@Valid
private Gamma g;
}
```

And validation rule:
If the user whose id will provided in URL has role "admin" that none of "a","b","g" properties can be null. If it has role "user" only "a" must be not null and other props must be null.

So basically these kind of rules can be easily implemented as class level-constraint of Alphabet class but custom validator would need somehow access id of the user which is provided in URL. Is there any smart way this could be achieved or i have to force all REST clients to pass user id multiple times: in URL and in payload so the latter will be only used by BV. 
The more complex case is when validation rule depends on logged in user, so custom validators will have to somehow access authenticated principal - from ThreadLocal or HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups):

```
//Define validation groups
interface AdminChecks {}
interface UserChecks {}

//Assign the constraints to the two groups
class Alphabet{

    @NotNull(groups={AdminChecks.class, UserChecks.class})
    private Alpha a;

    @NotNull(groups=AdminChecks.class)
    @Null(groups=UserChecksChecks.class)
    private Beta b;

    @NotNull(groups=AdminChecks.class)
    @Null(groups=UserChecksChecks.class)
    private Gamma g;
}
```

Depending on the role of the current user, you then specify either `AdminChecks` or `UserChecks` when invoking the validator, e.g. like this for the admin checks:

```
Validator validator = ...;
Set<ConstraintViolation<Alphabet>> violations = validator.validate(
    new Alphabet(),
    AdminChecks.class
);
```

Comment: Thx Gunnar for answer. I oversimplified my example too much.The real validation rule is like: if user is guest and belongs to a workgroup which disallows changing gamma for guests than gamma property must be null but if workgroup allows changes to gamma for guest than gamma must not be null. The similar rules applies to Beta, Alpha and other properties. All of these properties are independent - you can have workgroups that allow both gamma and beta for guests but disallows alpha - any combination possible. I just can not model it with validation groups and have to use class level constraints